# django haystack elasticsearch multiple search fields

Tags: django, search, elasticsearch

I have successfully implemented the haystack search engine for 2 models. Those models are meant to be searched within the same field so that is ok. But now I want a different search index for a new model and this index has no connection with the first 2 and will be used on a different page with a different search field. 
I don't know how to do this. 
I read that I can use 2 engines like this, but after the settings I don't know how to tell in the views to use a different model for the second search.

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack',
        'EXCLUDED_INDEXES': ['names.search_indexes.NamesIndex'],
    },
    'autocomplete': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'autcomplete',
         'EXCLUDED_INDEXES': ['players.search_indexes.PlayersIndex', 'allauth.search_indexes.UserIndex'],
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet

sqs = SearchQuerySet(using='autocomplete')
```